# getResourceAsStream returns null under Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader().getClass()

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-resources-plugin

So The currently the loading configuration used by the library is

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream in = loader.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/a.properties") // null
```

But when I tried to debug the application, the following expression contains the file

```
loader.getResourceAsStream("properties/a.properties")
```

I am using IntelliJ IDE and Maven build tool. The resources are copied into the target folder. And using IntelliJ run command to run the class currently.

Since the code is from the library, I can't modify it. What is the problem here and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible workaround is to downgrade the Java version to a non-module version (less than 9), so that the code works.